# Network time discrepancy affecting sync

Tags: web3js, truffle, testnets, ropsten

I'm trying to deploy a contract to the Ropsten testnet using Truffle. Already tested on testrpc, worked smoothly. I keep getting the error "Exceeds block gas limit" when I try to deploy to testnet. Even when I am not specifying any gas amounts anywhere, I always get the same error.

I noticed the following warning in the geth client, which might be affecting my network, since it seems like I'm unable to mine blocks and get ether like before.

```
WARN [07-27|12:26:21] System clock seems off by 20.321575601s, which can prevent network connectivity 
WARN [07-27|12:26:21] Please enable network time synchronisation in system settings.
```

I'm running macOS 10.12.5 and followed the [instructions here](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH18804?locale=en_US) a while ago, but it clearly didn't resolve my issue. Other people who get time synchronization errors seem to be on Windows. How do I fix this on a mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way to sync time on my mac. Instructions here: http://osxdaily.com/2012/07/04/set-system-time-mac-os-x-command-line/

Basically ran the following in my command line:

```
sudo ntpdate -u time.apple.com
```

I was able to proceed after doing this.